# Can conventional File.CreateText(path) be used instead of IsolatedStorageFile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Seems everyone assumes you have to use Isolated Storage on Windows Phone 8, but I haven't found the *why*.  I've also used some code I was porting, and conventional `File.CreateText(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation)` seems to work fine.

So in code, everyone seems to be doing [this (from developer.nokia.com)](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/File_manipulation_with_IsolatedStorageFile_on_Windows_Phone):

```
IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, fileStorage));
Writer.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
Writer.Close();
```

That's actually exceptionally tame. I've seen too many beginner tutorials that makes that `async`, and can't figure out why. The above code is presented within a WP7 context, however.

---

**UPDATE: Though the below code worked on WP8 (HTC 8XT) and WP8.1 (Lumia 640) when run from Visual Studio, when I deployed to the store, it blew up *immediately* when I tried to save to a file.**

---

The below code seems to work just as well, at least on the WP emulator, my HTC 8XT running Windows Phone 8, and my Lumia 640 running WP 8.1.  Code below can be seen in marginally better context [at this link](http://catchingmono.blogspot.com/2014/09/easy-text-files-on-windows-phone.html), but this is the important stuff.  Yes, I'm using some hungarian.  Sorry.  Obviously your page needs to have a TextBox named `txtText` and a global called `strFileLoc`.

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package =
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = 
    package.InstalledLocation;
this.strFileLoc = Path.Combine(installedLocation.Path, 
    "myFile.txt");

string strToWrite = this.txtText.Text;
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(this.strFileLoc))
{
    sw.WriteLine(strToWrite);
    sw.Close();
}

// Load
string strText = string.Empty;
if (File.Exists(this.strFileLoc))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = 
        new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(this.strFileLoc)))
    {
        strText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
else
{
    strText = "File doesn't exist";
}
this.txtText.Text = strText;
```

**Can this be used in a production app? Why or why not?**

Comment: I know. Blame [this guy](http://www.xoc.net/training/default.asp) from, shoot, 15+ years ago. It's a curse. ;^) It's a sample app, at least. Real code has horrible stuff like `this.txtPrice.Text`. /sigh I only do it for personal projects, I *swear!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works while debugging since the VS-based deployment gives your app write access to your install location (an annoying bug / design issue). When your app is deployed from the Store, it doesn't have permissions to the install location and will crash. The solution is to not try and create (or write to) files in your installation folder; use one of your [`ApplicationData` folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) instead.

As to using synchronous vs asynchronous methods, there are two answers. The first answer is that assuming you are making calls from your UI thread, asynchronous methods allow your UI to remain responsive even if the I/O takes a long time (as it might do when loading from an SD card, for example). Relying on synchronous APIs means your UI might glitch or appear to have crashed.

The second answer is that the `System.IO` APIs are not valid for Universal apps across Windows 8/8.1, so if you wanted to re-use code you had no choice but to use the `...Async` WinRT APIs.

Starting with Windows 10 Universal apps, you can use `System.IO.File` again across all Windows device families. And since you can set the current directory, you *could* do something like this:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);
using (var f = File.CreateText("hello.txt"))
{
  f.WriteLine("Hello, world");
}
```

Note that the current directory is a **process-wide** setting, so avoid this kind of code in general (setting it in different threads to different values will only result in tears), but it is useful if you have existing code that relies on relative paths. Also note that ideally you would only run code such as the above in a background thread, due to the chance that it will take some time to complete.

Comment: So if I just swap up to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path`, I should be okay? Is there any reason most tutorials want to write & read files [with async methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/04/how-to-store-json-data-in-windows-phone-8.aspx) instead? Thanks!

Comment: What does "blows up" mean? And can you post the code that is blowing up? Note that you can't use the `System.IO` APIs in a Windows [Phone] 8.x app.

Comment: Looks like I'd screwed up uploading packages -- tried again last night with a lot more (so *almost* enough) debugging code, and it all worked, no [operational] changes. Thanks again, and apologies for the red herring. One more app in the Store!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall right, files are left alone during the update progress from the Windows Store.  As for your other question it is a matter of platforms you're wishing to target (like most things related to developing for WP7-8.1/WIN8/WinRT)...  refer to this MSDN forum page

[Storage vs IsolatedStorage](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9379f64e-c322-4198-a0c3-80e03603ffa0/storage-vs-isolatedstorage)

---

Copied from MSDN Forum

> Ah, ApplicationData vs IsolatedStorage.  OK, In all honesty, there isn't a big difference between them as far as performance goes.  It's more about application development choices.  If you are writing for WP7.1 and 8 you MUST use IsolatedStorage as ApplicationData.LocalFolder isn't available in 7.x.  If you want to write code that is available in both Win8/WinRT and WinPhone then you must use ApplicationData as IsolatedStorage isn't supported in Windows 8.  Both APIs are completely safe and data stored can only be accessed from the App that created it.
>
> So it comes down to where you want to use your code.  I suggest you use ApplicationData if you are starting from scratch and don't care about WP7.x as that is the direction that all MS OSs are moving.
>
> If this is the answer, please mark it as the answer.
>
> Cheers, Mark B Schramm

Comment: Interesting. So am I using "ApplicationData"? That is, is `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation` in my code related to `ApplicationData.LocalFolder`? Either way, is there an advantage to using `LocalFolder`? Perhaps most importantly, **are you saying that my code *wouldn't* work on WP7?** I don't have a dev environment set up for 7, but if that's the case, I think the mystery's solved.

Comment: Fwiw, just temporarily released an app to the store, and my conventional writes blew up the app. Worked fine on a[n actual] Windows Phone in Device debug mode, but after downloading from the Store, BLAM.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work on Windows Phone platform and most specifically I owned the quality device update experience. User data , files and settings are persisted  in the updated process whether its in AppData or Isolated Storage.